# Gulp грузит процессор

Tags: gulp

Gulp под windows грузит процессор 50% и больше.
Можно ли уменьшить эту нагрузку.

Вот gulpfile.js:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass')

// Paths
var pathHtml        = 'themes/firstproject/*.html',
    pathScssStyle   = 'themes/firstproject/scss/style.scss',
    pathScssAdmin   = 'themes/firstproject/scss/admin.scss',
    pathScssFonts   = 'themes/firstproject/scss/fonts.scss',
    pathCss         = 'themes/firstproject/css/*.css',
    pathJs          = 'themes/firstproject/js/*.js',
    pathImgs        = 'themes/firstproject/img/**/*.*',
    pathFonts       = 'themes/firstproject/fonts/*/*.*',
    pathPhpMain     = 'themes/firstproject/*.php',
    pathPhp         = 'themes/firstproject/php/*.php',
    pathPlugins     = 'plugins/**/*.*',
    pathWooCom      = 'themes/firstproject/woocommerce/**/*.*'


// server connect
gulp.task('connect', function()
{
  connect.server(
  {
    root: 'dest',
    livereload: true
  })
})

// html
gulp.task('html', function()
{
    return gulp.src(pathHtml)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())


})


// scss - style
gulp.task('scss', function ()
{
  return gulp.src(pathScssStyle)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 15 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('admin-scss', function ()
{
  return gulp.src(pathScssAdmin)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 15 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject\\css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())
});

// scss - fonts
gulp.task('scss-fonts', function ()
{
  return gulp.src(pathScssFonts)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 15 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject\\fonts'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())
});

// css
gulp.task('css', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathCss)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject\\css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// js
gulp.task('js', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathJs)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject\\js'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// imgs
gulp.task('imgs', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathImgs)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject\\img'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// fonts
gulp.task('fonts', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathFonts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject\\fonts'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// php
gulp.task('phpMain', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathPhpMain)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// php
gulp.task('php', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathPhp)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\firstproject\\php'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// plugins php
gulp.task('plugins-php', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathPlugins)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\plugins'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// woocommerce php
gulp.task('woo-php', function ()
{
    gulp.src(pathWooCom)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\gvult\\wp-content\\themes\\woocommerce'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())

})

// watch
gulp.task('watch', function ()
{
    gulp.watch(pathScssStyle, ['scss'])
    gulp.watch(pathScssAdmin, ['admin-scss'])
    gulp.watch(pathCss, ['css'])
    gulp.watch(pathScssFonts, ['scss-fonts'])
    gulp.watch(pathJs, ['js'])
    gulp.watch(pathImgs, ['imgs'])
    gulp.watch(pathFonts, ['fonts'])
    gulp.watch(pathPhpMain, ['phpMain'])
    gulp.watch(pathPhp, ['php'])
    gulp.watch(pathPlugins, ['plugins-php'])
    gulp.watch(pathWooCom, ['woo-php'])
    gulp.watch(pathHtml, ['html'])
})

// default
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 
                        'scss',
                        'admin-scss',
                        'scss-fonts',
                        'css',
                        'js',
                        'imgs',
                        'fonts',
                        'phpMain',
                        'php',
                        'plugins-php',
                        'woo-php',
                        'html',
                        'watch'])
```

Comment: Вы создаете тонну вотчеров и жалуетесь на загрузку процессора, это понятно, т.к. он на каждый файл и папку вешает слушатель на изменение, некоторые вещи можно убрать, что-то вынести в статику. Это уже ваша оптимизация. PS. Сделайте нормальные пути, а не ведите их начиная с диска.

Comment: Спасибо за коммент, смысл понял, буду думать. Пути начиная с диска так удобней, относительные это не вариант. Мне нужно слушать все файлы, я не знаю какой файл буду править в следующий раз. Не могу понять что можно вынести в статику?

Comment: Картинки/шрифты, зачастую не меняются а только добавляются, но слушать изменение картинки это ерунда какая-то, они должны быть external, не понятно зачем вы слушаете php файлы гулпом, что за мода такая?) А на счет путей, это не может быть удобно, т.к. вы в итоге работает в одной папке, это ваш проект, гулп не должен выходить за пределы проекта, не нарушайте логику построения.

Comment: Картинки и шрифты, согласен спасибо. А чем слушать php я в нем все правлю. По поводу путей щас объясню. Где-то на диске мой проект, где я все правлю. Гулп мне все перезаписывает в папочку локального сервера. И почему гулп не должен выходить за пределы проекта? Еще раз за картинки спасибо переосмыслил.

Comment: Погодите, что вы правите в php, это серверный код, он не должен собираться гулпом, т.к. гулп собирает клиентскую часть. Поэтому не понятно что вы там собираете. Про выход за пределы проекта: все ваши зависимости, картинки, файлы, все должно быть в проекте, либо как зависимость либо как именно файл в нужном месте. Пример: вы переносите проект ваш куда либо на внешний сервер, все скопировали, и вдруг какие то картинки не загрузились, а понять почему вы не можете, вам придется менять пути на сервера на нужные, т.к. расположение будет иным, а так все пути внутри проекта

Comment: Все я понял, спасибо за разъяснения. В принципе да, нафига мне копировать php файлы если я их на месте могу править. Блин, все упрощается на данном этапе разработки проекта мне нужен только sass в гулпе. На счет путей не согласен. У меня рабочий вариант проекта на локальном сервере. И я беру собираю файл сасс прямо на свой сервер. почему нет. Надо поработать на другом компе я поменял путь, а можно даже и не менять (смотря на ситуацию). А за понимание гулпа спасибо.

Comment: Про путь я тоже понял. Хорошо, что есть люди с которыми можно переписываться. Спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Удачного коддинга!